# DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: java, firebase, recyclerview

Me esta dando este fallo en un recyclerview y no se como solucionarlo,estoy intentando mostrar los events que tengo...  Uso otro recyclerView en la app y me funciona sin problemas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String avatar;
    private List<String> events;
    private String vote;


    //Constructor
    public User() {
        this.events = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public User(List<String> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String avatar) {

        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.events = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String avatar, List<String> events) {

        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.events = events;

    }
```

---

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<String> eventos;
AdapterGallery adapter;



public GalleryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista=inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false );

    FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    eventos = new ArrayList<>();


    recyclerView = vista.findViewById( R.id.rv_gallery );
    adapter=new AdapterGallery( eventos );
    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

    FirebaseUser userAut;
    userAut = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    database.getReference("Users").child(userAut.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                // String lista=snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                User lista=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                //RecyclerList lista=snapshot.getValue(RecyclerList.class);
                eventos=lista.getevents() ;// en debug lo recibe bien

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );


    return vista;
}
```

}

Comment: Para mi el error esta en que estas declarando la el `ArrayList` `eventos` sin especificar el tipo: `List eventos;`, en vez de hacer `List<String> eventos;`. Es ese el error?

Comment: Me faltaba por poner en el codigo      List<User> eventos    al hacer la pregunta, asi que eso es lo extraño, que lo defino y todo y el fallo sigue estando

Comment: Puede ser que events como no es un objeto me de fallo??? si es asi, como podria recoger los datos de dentro? tendria que crear otra clase con una lista para poder recogerlo o se puede hacer de alguna manera mas sencilla?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ahora no me muestra nada pero tampoco me da ningún fallo, mirare el adaptador y veré si soy capaz de arreglarlo

Comment: Pudiste resolver tu problema?

Comment: esta tarde he estado con el tutor y al final he dejado el fragment de esta manera, no crashea pero tampoco muestra los datos, usando el debug eventos recibe todos los datos del array, supongo que me faltara algun pequeño detalle. El viernes volvere a estar con el tutor y supongo que me lo arreglara, en cuanto lo haga subire la respuesta, gracias por tu atención Andres

Comment: También he usado tu metodo y lo mismo, no crashea pero tampoco muestra nada, seguramente sea algun fallo tonto, el viernes pondre la respuesta correcta y actualizare  la respuesta como aceptada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **problema** por el que te causa:

> DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to
>   type

es porque simplemente estás declarando la lista List sin especificar el tipo que obtendrás:

Haces:

```
List eventos;
```

En vez de:

```
List<User> eventos;
```

Y como el indicador `new ArrayList<>();` es abtracto, no toma el tipo que deseas si no lo especificas en el tipo generico de List.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es poblar tu adapter con eventos, que si nos fijamos en el arbol de Firebase, dicho nodo contiene hijos `String`, no basta con tener una `List<User>`, ya que `User` contiene todos las propiedades aunque solo asigne el valor a eventos.

Tienes dos opciones:

- **Recomendada** si tu adapter solo es manejado para mostrar "eventos": debes declarar la lista que maneja el adapter como `List<String>` y en vez pasarle los datos como `eventos.add(user);`, pasarlo asi:

`eventos.addAll(user.getEvents());`

debes eliminar el ciclo for, ya que solo tienes un nodo que maneja la lista.

- **Menos recomendada**: si vas a utilizar una lista donde solo necesitas el campo events de user. Deja todo como esta y en el adapter, obtienes el item que vas a mostrar, asi:

`items.getEvents().get(position);`

Asumiendo que `items` es tipo `List<User>` Y en el `getItemCount` deberías devolver:

```
items.events.size();
```

El problema de esta última es que vas a tener un objeto `User` con campos que no vas a utilizar.

**Al final te debería quedar algo así utilizando la opción recomenda:**

```
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    eventos.clear();

    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    eventos.addAll( user.getEvents() );

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Comment: Me faltaba en el recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( context ) ); todo solucionado, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @lujan excelente. buena suerte. Recuerda que puedes marcar mi respuesta como aceptada, si te sirvio.

Comment: Si es lo de darle a lo de esta respuesta es útil no me deja por que tengo menos de 15 de reputación, si es hacer otra cosa dímela y no tendré ningún problema en hacerlo

Comment: @lujan, no te deja votar, pero si te deja aceptarla, está debajo de la flecha de votar negativo la de aceptación. Si le das click √ te la marca verde.

Comment: Perfecto gracias!!!